# How to integrate Tailwind CSS to Laravel10?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I am going to integrate Tailwind CSS into Laravel.
I created Laravel project using follow command.

> composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app

But I am not sure how to install laravel Authentication and Tailwind CSS.
Also, when I create Laravel 10 with the above command, it generates vite.config.js file.
What should I do?

Comment: Hi, you can read about laravel starter kits on laravel official documentation. They have laravel breeze that already include authentication feature and tailwind css out of the box. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits

Comment: But there is not a description how to make authentication.

Comment: If you're using Laravel Breeze, you don't need to create authentication from scratch. Laravel Breeze includes authentication out of the box, and it uses a simple/straightforward authentication feature. After you follow the instruction of how to install laravel breeze, you can check the code to know how they implement the auth and you can find more details about the authentication here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication